# What equiment/software does Skrillex use?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design

Does anybody out there know what kind of equipment skrillex uses to make his mixes fused with dubstep?  Is it purely software or does use a mixed setup?  I am curious how he sets up his samples, and then drops with gnarly screams, scrathes, and other noise effects he throws on his tracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He uses software and hardware synths - including his main one, the FM8.

Some speculation on the dubstep forum that he uses Guitar Rig for some distortion effects.

To be honest this is probably the best source for information: [How To Sound Like Skrillex & Make Skrillex Bass](http://www.dubstepforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=198681) - a plethora of links, tutorials and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

At a broad level, he uses Ableton Live, which is popular with many similar producers such as Deadmau5. He also uses a Pioneer DJM 800 mixer and an EFX 1000 for effects.

Answer (score 1):

Skrillex uses Ableton Live. Mainly because of it’s flexibility and the unique ability to play live.

Almost anything you want can be done seamlessly in Ableton Live.

Even Deadmau5 uses Ableton Live.

You can eread more about it here - [Skrillex DAW and Gear](https://bassdropfactory.com/what-plugins-does-skrillex-use-gears-equipment/)!